# iOS Beta 5 SwiftUI List duplicates single item

Tags: ios, swiftui, beta

Has anyone else seen this in iOS 14 Beta 5? It worked fine in previous betas...

```
    @State private var favorites = [Truck]()
    @State private var favoritesRetreived = false

    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(favorites, id:\.id) { truck in
                NavigationLink (destination: TruckDetail(truck: truck)) {
                    TruckListItem(truck: truck)
                }
            }
        }
        .navigationBarTitle(Text("Favorites"), displayMode: .inline)
        .onAppear(perform: {
            getFavoriteTrucks()
        })
    }
```

The data in favorites is properly updated in the call to getFavoriteTrucks, but the list simply shows the first item duplicated for favorites.count number of times. I KNOW this was working correctly in previous betas... Did something change that I missed?

Comment: I would start by ensuring that `truck.id` is unique. Duplicate IDs can create they symptom you're describing (and in ways that vary from release to release).

Comment: Yes, all of the data in the truck is as it is expected to be. The truckIDs are unique. None of that changed between betas. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rob Napier, you were right. the .id I was using in the ForEach was not the value I should have been using. All of those values were "" so therefore the duplicates were being generated. THANKS!

Answer (score 0):

Check your value for id. It's not required to be mentioned in ForEach loop, but it should be unique in your model.

Ex:

ForEach(list.datas) {
i in
print(i.id)
}

This i.id must have unique value and should not be nil or empty,
For me it was an empty string.